# Promise.all return more values

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm trying to make two async calls running concurrently and waiting until they are finished with `Promise.all`. How can I make `Promise.all` return more than one value using async/await in es6 in nodejs? I wish I could see the assigned variables outside. This code is wrong but represents what I need.

```
  Promise.all([
    var rowA = await buildRow(example, countries),
    var rowM = await buildRow(example, countries)
  ])
  console.log(rowA+rowB)
```

Is there a way to see those variables outside the scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I make Promise.all return more than one value using
>   async/await in es6 in nodejs?

`Promise.all` resolved value is always an array where each item is the resolved value of the individual promises passed to it. The results are in the same order as the promises.

```
  const [rowA, rowB] = await Promise.all([
        buildRow(example, countries),
        buildRow(example, countries)
  ]);

  console.log(rowA, rowB);
```

Using destructuring we assign to `rowA` the first result, and `rowB` the second one.